# How do I make sure my webview can scale with devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I'm trying to get my webview to sit just above my Google Ad Mob ad.  However the web view always covers the entire screen unless I programatically try and adjust the height.  I've tried setting the height of the webview to the heigh of the screen subtracting my ad height, but that doesn't seem to work accurately on all devices.  What should my height of my webview be set to if I want my ad to sit just below the webview?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="320dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
ads:adUnitId="/serviceid/myadtagishere"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
android:layout_below="@+id/webView1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because height is set to fill_parent and your ad is below

Comment: I've tried setting it to just about everything, I can obviously set it to 500 dip, but of course that doesn't scale per device.

Comment: Just remove layout_below and set align_ParentBottom=true on your ad view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem using a linear layout.  This seems to be the easiest and most effective way of getting a google ad mob ad to show up below a webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:orientation="vertical">    

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
ads:adUnitId="/5773/sci.app.hoosierscoop"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="320dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip"
  ads:adUnitId="/serviceid/myadtagishere"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

The add view should be above the webview and the webview fullscreen.

Comment: I moved the adView above the webview and added the alignParentBottom but I'm still getting the webview covering the entire screen.

Comment: No, the adview has to be declared below the webview, that way it will be above the webview.